# Add Campaign information to Visualforce Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, campaign

I am wanting to incorporate campaign information into an email template that will be fired whenever an Opportunity is Closed Won. It appears that it is not possible to query the "Campaign Influence" object in Apex, I was wondering if anybody had an idea for a workaround?

I just want to be able to display campaign names in this template for the opportunity that triggers the email.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Primary Campaign Source is a standard field on Opportunity that's a look-up to Campaign. You shouldn't need to query Campaign if the fields on your Opportunity are properly populated prior to it being updated to closed-won.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, I needed to pull in multiple campaigns from the Campaign Influence object, seems like this is not possible.

Comment: That would be correct if using a template fired from workflow. Either that or you'd need to add custom fields to hold look-ups to the other influencers.